# How fix object required error in vba in with statement?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I want to create a button that, when the user presses it, will do this:

1. before press the button user mark name in pivot table on sheet Eff
2. after press button the same name will be filter in another pivot table on sheet Pivot_All

[image]

I tried this, but in `.PivotItems(a(g)).Visible = True` it gives me object required error

```
Public Function GetLength(a As Variant) As Integer
   If IsEmpty(a) Then
      GetLength = 0
   Else
      GetLength = UBound(a) - LBound(a) + 1
End If
 GL = GetLength
End Function

Public Function a(ByVal rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim f As Long, r As Range
    ReDim arr(1 To rng.Count)

    f = 1
    For Each r In rng.Cells
        arr(f) = r.Value
        f = f + 1
     Next r

  a = arr
End Function

Sub Macro6()
 Dim rngCopy As Range
 Dim rngPaste As Range
 Dim rng As Range
 Set rng = Selection

  Sheets("Pivot_All").Activate

  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Empl").ClearAllFilters
  With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Empl")
    For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count - 1
        .PivotItems(.PivotItems(i).Name).Visible = False
    Next i
 End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Empl")
      For g = 0 To GL
        .PivotItems(a(g)).Visible = True
      Next g
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `a` is waiting for a range `a(ByVal rng As Range)` but you submit a number `g` as parameter. You must submit a `Range` object instead.

Comment: Do you mean something  like `For Each cell In a
       .PivotItems(a(cell)).Visible = True
       Next cell`?

Comment: See my edited answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` is waiting for a range `a(ByVal rng As Range)` but you submit a number `g` as parameter. You must submit a `Range` object instead.

Also `GL` is not defined in your procedure, I assume you wanted to use `GetLength` instead.

So it should be something like:

```
Dim ResultOfA As Variant
ResultOfA = a(Range("your range here"))

For g = 0 To GetLength(ResultOfA) 
    .PivotItems(ResultOfA(g)).Visible = True
Next g
```

I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

---

Note that you can read a continous range into an array in one line:

```
Dim ArrValues() As Variant
ArrValues = Range("A1:A10").Value

Debug.Print ArrValues(1, 5) '= A5
```

If you use this you might not need your function `a` anymore.

---

You would end up with something like:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Macro6()
    Dim rngCopy As Range
    Dim rngPaste As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Selection

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Pivot_All")

    With ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Empl")
        .ClearAllFilters

        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count - 1
            .PivotItems(.PivotItems(i).Name).Visible = False
        Next i

        Dim ResultOfA As Variant
        ResultOfA = a(rng)

        If Not IsEmpty(ResultOfA) Then
            Dim g As Long
            For g = LBound(ResultOfA) To UBound(ResultOfA)
                .PivotItems(ResultOfA(g)).Visible = True
            Next g
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Public Function a(ByVal rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim f As Long, r As Range
    ReDim arr(1 To rng.Count)

    f = 1
    For Each r In rng.Cells
        arr(f) = r.Value
        f = f + 1
    Next r

    a = arr
End Function
```

Comment: `GL` is defined as `GL = GetLength` in `GetLength` function. It will work if it is a public variable.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij This doesn't make any sense at all if it is a function that returns the value it should not write into a global variable (then it should be a procedure instead). I recommend to use `Option Explicit` an delete the `GL = GetLength` line from the function.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I didn't comment from coding practice point of view but just to indicate that it is defined in OP's code. I am not personally comfortable with coding aspects of the code posted e.g. defining a function just named `a` but that was not the question.